How to remove small tilde and other special characters from excel?
I am learning excel from scratch, and I have a dataset of around 7000 entries. Some of these entries have texts such as:

This obviously is not clean data, and I wish to highlight it. I tried using conditional formatting, but failed. I tried get rid of the special characters altogether, but have been failing to do so as well. Some solutions on the internet suggest using developer mode and writing up a VBA code myself. Is that the only solution? If there is another simpler way to highlight/clean my data, please help.
Conditional formatting - hihglight cells containging text
Find and Replace
Find only

As far as i can understand, conditional formatting has nothing to do with your problem. Ye, you might create a condition to highlight cells with special character, but it would be basically a waste of time. You probably want to search and replace the unwanted characters. If you have to do it just once for a small dataset, you might do it manually. Otherwise i'd say that a VBA code is much likely the way. Do you have a set of acceptable characters?

In case it isn't clear, the underlying problem here is character encoding. Either you are reading your dataset using the wrong encoding (e.g. Windows-1252 when it should be UTF-8) or your dataset has already been mangled at source. If the former, you might be able to fix this by reading the file using the correct encoding Also, what do you consider to be a "special character"? Is the first character of the correct form "À la carte" a "special" character? Removing that character would leave " la carte" which would be wrong.

If you tried to use conditional formatting and failed, then you are doing something wrong. Since you chose not to share your attempt, it will not be possible to assess where you went wrong. Suggest you edit your question  after reading the HELP pages for information as to How to Ask a Good Question, and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

The simpler method to clean the data would be to start at the source and import it correctly as noted by @NeilT If that is not possible, then you will need to first precisely define special character.

You can do it with Word Regex which Excel not support.

Copy the Excel range to the Clipboard
Open Word
Paste clipboard content as Use destination styles get a table.
Click Replace -> More -> Check Use wildcards
Type in Replace what:  [!a-z,A-Z]  mod as required e.g. numbers
Leave Replace with empty
Click Replace All
Select the corrected test and Copy
Select the target cell in Excel and Paste
Close Word

